# Remove quotes from array value

Tags: arrays, angular, postgresql, multidimensional-array

I have a response from postgres DB that includes qoutes around an array

```
images: "[{"image":"https://dw901jjvwj0lk.cloudfront.net/smart-address/image/gift certificate/afa9b56f-ddb4-4ae5-b72b-afae20129ea4/gift certificate/IMG_5076.JPG"}]"
info: "[{"balance_owo":0,"balance_btc":0,"btc_address":0,"btc_qr":null,"price_usd":25,"details":"use this gift certificate at sweet sosumba on Georgia and Park NW","quantity":500,"quantity_left":null}]"
```

the quotes are preventing *ngFor from realizing this is an array

I've tried removing the quotes from the DB using jsonb returns =, but thant doesn't work.

```
$query=$dbh->prepare("SELECT *, earth_distance(ll_to_earth($user_lat,$user_lng), ll_to_earth(lat, lng)) as local_distance
FROM tribe.smart_address
WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth($user_lat,$user_lng), $fence) @> ll_to_earth(lat, lng) AND active=:one
ORDER by date_created DESC");
$query->bindValue(':one', 1);
$query->execute();
$gifts = $query -> fetchAll()
```

I've also tried

```
[src]="removeQuotes(data.images)"
[src]="data.images[0].image"
```

nothing works... sanitizing doesn't work either... how do I fix, please

here's the angular code that grabs data from the DB

```
    this.$local.gift_start(this.user_token, this.user_id, 
  this.user_lat, this.user_lng, this.type)
  .then((jordi: any) => {
    if (jordi.success) {
      this.Dsmart = jordi.payload[0]
   }
  )
```

returns promise from the service

```
    return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.post('https://owo.world/app/gift/start', DATA, httpOptions)
    .subscribe(data => {
      resolve(data);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

front page

```
<div class="card current_progress" *ngFor="let data of 
   Dsmart; let i = index">
          <a [href]="data[i].images"> <img class="img-fluid img-raised" 
  [src]="data[i].images[0].image" alt=""> </a>
```

it's not able . to get the image, because it's returned as a string... need to remove the quotes to make it work

Comment: Isn't is JSON?, `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: it's JSON... JSON parse returns Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
it's encoded on the php side
echo json_encode($data,true);

Comment: Could you please provide the code that returns the json string to angular?

Comment: I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
$gifts = json_decode($gifts)
```

to your PHP-code. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Or, as xyz suggests, parse it on the javascript side, like

```
JSON.parse(data)
```

After all, it's not about the quotes, bhut that it has to be understoos as JSON by your Javascript-Code in the end.